# How to run SOQL for an Object having more than 200K records?

Tags: apex, trigger, selectivity, queryexception

I’m trying to populate a **custom lookup field** called Part Name( API Name: **Part_Number__c**) on Case Object, where Part Name field is a lookup to Product Object( Maps to Product Name).

We’ve 3 Picklist fields called Product Family, Product Name, and Component Workflow on Case as well as Product Object.

Anytime support agent chooses a combination of Product Family, Product Name, and Component Workflow on Case Record, it must populate custom lookup field called Part Name( API Name: **Part_Number__c**) for matching corresponding values of Product Family, Product Name, and Component Workflow on Product record.

Although Trigger I've written is not throwing any error when I save the trigger, it is throwing below error when I’m trying to create a case record.

> Error: Invalid Data.
>
> Review all error messages below to correct your data. Apex trigger
>   UpdatePartName caused an unexpected exception, contact your
>   administrator: UpdatePartName: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by:
>   System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type
>   (more than 200000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact
>   salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is indexed a
>   filter might still not be selective when: 1. The filter value includes
>   null (for instance binding with a list that contains null) 2. Data
>   skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for
>   instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs
>   many times): Trigger.UpdatePartName: line 9, column 1

**Below is the Apex Trigger:**

```
trigger UpdatePartName on Case (before insert,before update) {
    Set<Id> pIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Case c: trigger.new) {
        if(string.isBlank(c.Part_Number__c)) {  
            pIds.add(c.Part_Number__c);
        }
        if(!pIds.isEmpty())
        {
            for(Product2 pnames: [Select Id from Product2 WHERE Product_Family__c != null AND Product_Family__c = :c.Product_Family_new__c AND Product_Name__c != null AND Product_Name__c = :c.Product_Name_new__c AND Component_Workflow__c != null AND Component_Workflow__c = :c.Product_Component__c LIMIT 1])    
            {
                c.Part_Number__c = pnames.Id;
                update pnames;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure making [A custom index](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002493&type=1) on the field (Part_Number__c) by contacting Salesforce Support will work as I'm using Bind Variable inside SOQL.

> Per Renato's suggestion I've written the code with different approach.
>   Code compiles now with no error, but upon Case record creation ***it
>   is throwing the exact same error.***

**Modified trigger**

```
trigger UpdatePartName on Case (before insert, before update) {
    // store all your variables to search
    List<String> families = new List<String>();
    List<String> names = new List<String>();
    List<String> components = new List<String>();
    for (Case record : Trigger.new) {
        // get the parameters that will be used on the query
        if (!string.isBlank(record.Product_Family_new__c)&& !string.isBlank(record.Product_Name_new__c) && !string.isBlank(record.Product_Component__c) && string.isBlank(record.Part_Number__c)) {
            families.add(record.Product_Family_new__c);
            names.add(record.Product_Name_new__c);
            components.add(record.Product_Component__c);
        }
    }
    // remove duplicates
    families = new List<String>(new Set<String>(families));
    names = new List<String>(new Set<String>(names));
    components = new List<String>(new Set<String>(components));
    // query matching products
    List<Product2> products = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Product_Family__c IN :families AND Product_Name__c IN :names AND Component_Workflow__c IN :components];
    // assign them to cases
    for (Case record : Trigger.new) {
        for (Product2 pro : products) {
            if (pro.Product_Family__c !=null && pro.Product_Name__c != null && pro.Component_Workflow__c != null) {
                record.Part_Number__c = pro.Id;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly. You want the agent to select 3 values on the case object, and based on those values get a product that fits those and assign it to the relationship?

Comment: Yes. We’ve 3 Picklist fields called Product Family, Product Name, and Component Workflow on Case as well as Product Object.

Comment: There are many other posts on Salesforce StackExchange about non-selective query issues.  Have you look through those?

Comment: You must not do any bulk actions on your `Case` object. You have a query inside a for loop, that's bulkification 101.

Comment: Also querying on a field being not null and equal to a specific value makes the query less selective than simply filtering on the field being equal to that specific value.

Comment: @DavidCheng Yes

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've tried w/o != null initially but it was throwing same  error, so I've ended up appending that with != null

Comment: Well that only made matters worse.

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this:

```
trigger UpdatePartName on Case (before insert, before update) {
    // store all your variables to search
    List<String> families = new List<String>();
    List<String> names = new List<String>();
    List<String> components = new List<String>();
    for (Case record : Trigger.new) {
        // get the parameters that will be used on the query
        if (record.Family__c != null && record.ProductName__c != null && record.Component__c != null) {
            families.add(record.Family__c);
            names.add(record.ProductName__c);
            components.add(record.Component__c);
        }
    }
    // remove duplicates
    families = new List<String>(new Set<String>(families));
    names = new List<String>(new Set<String>(names));
    components = new List<String>(new Set<String>(components));
    // query matching products
    List<Product> products = [SELECT Id FROM Product WHERE Family IN :families AND PartNumber__c IN :names AND Component__c IN :components];
    // assign them to cases
    for (Case record : Trigger.new) {
        for (Product pro : products) {
            if (/* check three fields here*/) {
                record.Product__c = pro.Id;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why create a list and then turn the list into a set and then turn it back into a list. Why not just create the sets and then add the values to them. Set will de-dup automatically and you can use the sets straight in the query. A lot of extra code that you don't need.

Comment: Wouldn't call that "a lot" but you are right. Sets can be passed to the query directly.

Comment: Code dump with no explanation?

Comment: I was under the impression that the comments within the code were enough.

Comment: They certainly can be. Kind of hard to spot the crux of this answer though. Also some of  the syntax won't compile (missing `new` keywords for example).

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Made the changes per your suggestion however it is throwing compilation errors for below 3 lines:

'families = List<String>(new Set<String>(families));
    names = List<String>(new Set<String>(names));
    components = List<String>(new Set<String>(components));'

**Errors are**
Unexpected token '='.
Unexpected token '<'.
Variable does not exist: String